# Disable Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to disable syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2 when opening a particular file? Or to disable it completely (without restarting the application)?

Some background: Sometimes I'd want to open some large data file, but this takes minutes with syntax highlighting enabled. For example, Sublime Text takes several minutes to open a 6MB JSON file. If I use an unknown extension on this JSON file, it gets loaded within several seconds. But changing the file extension is an ugly hack.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution 1

Go to **View** menu **→ Syntax → Plain Text**. This works, but not in the same session - upon sublime text restart.

### Solution 2

If you want sublime text remember go to **View → Syntax → Open all with current extension as → Plain Text**.

### Solution 3

You could also create a new color scheme that only defines a base foreground color but no colors for syntax elements. See http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html. (Basically, you only want global settings and no scoped settings.)

Answer (score 0):

See this plugin:

https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax/

It uses a map and a listener plugin:
  class ApplySyntaxCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
      def on_new(self, view):
to set a new syntax for the file. For a log file you could use Plain Text.

I'm not sure if this is done before or after the file is opened though... it could not solve your performance issues, give it a try :)